# d3 elements not rendering in React

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

So I did a a [treemap](https://codepen.io/TaraBryn/pen/XWrwbON) for [freecodecamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/) and it's working fine, but I wanted to make it a bit more dynamic, to let the user choose which dataset to visualize (there's a choice of three datasets). To do this I found [this Medium article](https://medium.com/@Elijah_Meeks/interactive-applications-with-react-d3-f76f7b3ebc71) explaining how to integrate d3 into react.

Essentially, in my `render` method I used `ref={node=>this.node=node}` for the ref attribute in the `div` being returned by the method, and am creating a function that renders the data onto that `div` using the reference and calling the function in `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`.

The problem I'm having is that the `rect` elements in the svg aren't rendering.

I know the integration is working because the first thing I rendered with the function is an `h4` header. The next thing I rendered is the `svg` element. I know the `svg` is rendering, because I can change the `background-color` in the CSS and it appears fine. I know the d3 hierarchy is working because I displayed `root.leaves()` in the console and it displayed the appropriate data. I'm not getting any error messages and I know the entire `createMap` method is running b/c I can log something to the console fine at the end of the function. I thought maybe it was an issue with the color scale, so I set the `fill` of the `rect`s to `black` and still got nothing.

[Here is a link to my project](https://codepen.io/TaraBryn/pen/92d921ad5a58422c14bbead50fac47be?editors=0010) and below is the JS code. Can anyone tell me what's going on with it?

```
$(function(){

  const DATASETS = [
    {
      TYPE: 'KICKSTARTERS',
      NAME: 'Kickstarters',
      URL: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/freeCodeCamp/testable-projects-fcc/a80ce8f9/src/data/tree_map/kickstarter-funding-data.json'
    },
    {
      TYPE: 'MOVIES',
      NAME: 'Movies',
      URL: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/freeCodeCamp/testable-projects-fcc/a80ce8f9/src/data/tree_map/movie-data.json'
    },
    {
      TYPE: 'GAMES',
      NAME: 'Games',
      URL: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/freeCodeCamp/testable-projects-fcc/a80ce8f9/src/data/tree_map/video-game-sales-data.json'
    }
  ];

  //REDUX
  const INDEX = 'INDEX';
  const INITIAL_STATE = 0;

  //action generator
  function setIndex(index){
    return {
      type: INDEX,
      index
    };
  }

  //reducer
  function indexReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action){
    switch(action.type){
      case INDEX: return action.index;
      default: return state;
    }
  }

  const store = Redux.createStore(indexReducer);

  //react
  class DropDown extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
    }
    handler(e){
      this.props.setIndex(e.target.selectedIndex);
    }
    render(){
      return (
        <select 
          id='dropdown'
          onChange={this.handler}>
          {DATASETS.map(e=><option>{e.NAME}</option>)}
        </select>
      )
    }
  }

  class Svg extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.createMap = this.createMap.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount(){
      this.createMap();
    }
    componentDidUpdate(){
      this.createMap();
    }
    createMap(){
      const NODE = this.node
      const DATASET = DATASETS[this.props.index];
      d3.select(NODE)
      .html('')
      .append('h4')
      .attr('id', 'description')
      .attr('class', 'text-center')
      .html(`Top ${DATASET.NAME}`)

      //svg setup
      const SVG_PADDING = 20;
      const SVG_WIDTH = 1000;
      const SVG_HEIGHT = 1400;

      var svg = d3.select(NODE)
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', SVG_WIDTH)
      .attr('height', SVG_HEIGHT)
      .attr('id', 'map');

      d3.json(DATASET.URL)
      .then(
      function(data){
        //heirarchy and map
        var root = d3.hierarchy(data)
        .sum(d=>d.balue)
        .sort((a,b)=>b.height-a.height || b.value-a.value);

        var nodes = d3.treemap()
        .size([SVG_WIDTH, SVG_HEIGHT *  2/3])
        .padding(1)(root)
        .descendants();

        //scale
        var categories = [...new Set(root.leaves().map(e => e.data.category))].sort();
        var unityScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, categories.length]).range([0,1]);
        var colorScale = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateRainbow);
        var discreteScale = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20b);

        //map cells
        var cell = svg.selectAll('.cell')
        .data(root.leaves())
        .enter().append('g')
        .attr('class', 'cell')
        .attr('transform', d=>`translate(${d.x0}, ${d.y0})`);

        cell.append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'tile')
        .attr('data-category', d=>d.data.category)
        .attr('data-name', d=>d.data.name)
        .attr('data-value', d=> d.data.value)
        .attr('x', 0).attr('y', 0)
        .attr('width', d=>d.x1-d.x0)
        .attr('height', d=>d.y1-d.y0)
        .attr('fill', d => colorScale(unityScale(categories.indexOf(d.data.category))))
      });

    }
    render(){
      const test = d3.select('#container')
      return <div ref={node=>this.node=node}/>
    }
  }

  //ReactRedux
  const Provider = ReactRedux.Provider;
  const connect = ReactRedux.connect;

  function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return {
      setIndex: index=>dispatch(setIndex(index))
    }
  }

  function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
      index: state
    }
  }

  const DropDownConnection = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(DropDown);
  const SvgConnection = connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Svg);

  class Wrapper extends React.Component {
    render(){
      return(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <DropDownConnection/>
          <SvgConnection/>
        </Provider>
      )
    }
  }

  ReactDOM.render(<Wrapper/>, $('#container')[0]);
})
```